# Could someone please provide an example of the adjective "frisch" in the genitive?

Tags: genitive

I am making a few tables to help me memorize adjective declensions and I realize that I am unable to think of simple sentences in the genitive. In my table, for each of the genders + plural in genitive I have:
*frischen Käses, frischer Milch, frischen Brotes*, and *frischer Äpfel*. If somebody could provide me with a sentence in which any one of these is used, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the preposition *wegen* or *trotz*. They take genitive.

> Allein wegen frischer Milch geh ich doch nicht los!

> Trotz frischen Brotes war das Frühstück nur mittelprächtig.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, things take a slightly different turn when you add an article: *des frischen Käses (m), der frische**n** Milch (f), des frischen Brotes (n), and der frische**n** Äpfel (pl).*

Answer (score 6):

In the following examples for [*frisch*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:frisch#frisch_(Deklination)_(Deutsch)), the strong declension of is always followed by the weak declension.

Maskulin:

- Ich mag den Geruch *frischen* Käses.
- Ich mag den Geruch *des frischen* Käses.

Feminin:

- Die Farbe *frischer* Milch ist weiß.
- Die Farbe *der frischen* Milch ist weiß.

Neutrum:

- Der Duft *frischen* Brotes zog durch die Backstube.
- Der Duft *des frischen* Brotes zog durch die Backstube.

Plural:

- Ich mag den Geschmack *frischer* Äpfel.
- Ich mag den Geschmack *der frischen* Äpfel.